# unterminated string literal in the variable

Tags: javascript

```
var MM = '\' + obj[0]['MM '] + '/';
```

I get two errors while using this code...

> missing; before statement  **and** 
>   unterminated string literal

Comment: This is probably the only question on SO that mentions "MenstrualPeriod'. I lold pretty hard at that one... =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The character `\` is "special" because it's used to allow the use of all printable characters in strings. In your case `'\'` is not a string composed by the only character `\`, but the beginning of a string starting with the single quote character `'`.

For exampe if you want the string `Hello Andrea "6502" Griffini` you can use single quotes

```
string1 = 'Hello Andrea "6502" Griffini';
```

and if you want single quotes in the string you can do the opposite

```
string2 = "Hello Andrea '6502' Griffini";
```

But what if you want both kind of quotes in the same string? This is where the escape `\` character comes handy:

```
string3 = "'llo Andrea \"6502\" Griffini";
```

Basically `\` before a quote or double quote in a string tells javascript that **the following character is just a regular character, with no special meaning attached to it**.

Note that the very same character is also used in regular expressions... for example if you want to look for an open bracket `[` you must prefix it with a backslash because `[` in a regular expression has a special meaning.

The escape is also used to do the **opposite**... in a string if you put a backslash in front of a normal character you are telling javascript that that character is indeed special... for example

```
alert("This is\na test");
```

In the above line the `\n` sequence means a **newline** code, so the message displayed will be on two lines ("This is" and "a test").

You may now wonder... what if I need a backslash character in my string? Just double it in that case. In your code for example just use `'\\'`.

Here is a table for the possible meanings of backslash in strings

```
\"       just a regular double-quote character, it doesn't end the string
\'       just a regular single-quote character, it doesn't end the string
\b       a backspace character (ASCII code 0x08)
\t       a tab character (ASCII code 0x09)
\n       a newline character (ASCII code 0x0A)
\v       a vertical tab character (ASCII code 0x0B)
\f       a form feed character (ASCII code 0x0C)
\r       a carriage return character (ASCII code 0x0D)
\033     the character with ASCII code 033 octal = 27 ("ESC" in this case)
\x41     the character with ASCII code 0x41 = 65 ("A" in this case)
\u05D0   the unicode character 0x05D0 (Aleph from the Hebrew charset)
\\       just regular backslash character, not an escape prefix
```

Answer (score 3):

`\` is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). You'll have to double it to literally mean a backslash character, otherwise it'll augment the following character (In this case the next single quote)

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly escape the backslash:

```
var lastMenstrualPeriod = '\\' + obj[0]['LastMenstrualPeriod'] + '/';
```

Being escape character, the JS "compiler" is expecting another character to follow, for example `\n` is newline constant, `\t` is tab etc.. so `\\` is one single backslash in a string.

It is also mentioned in [Douglas Crockford book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=%22escape%20character%22%20Javascript%20douglas&source=bl&ots=HImjs1p2dK&sig=MwKe90aDuFgfAFRRB6VtQQtXvPk&hl=en&ei=4Ds-Tu3fBMzysgb79eH9Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to escape '\'

Do this:

```
var lastMenstrualPeriod = '\\' + obj[0]['LastMenstrualPeriod'] + '/';
```